# Zend prevent sending email that exists in database

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, email, email-validation

I have a form that send multiple emails at once separate them with a colon using zend framework.

Is there a way to prevent sending emails that already exists in database and send those that doesn't exists?

here's some here:

html -----

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'inviteByEmail'); ?>">
            <table><tr>
                <td>Email Addresses:* <span class="right small_font" style="margin-right:25px;">* Each email address must be separated by a comma ( , )</span></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input class="input_long" type="text" name="emails" /></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><br/>Personalize your message:</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><textarea cols="49" rows="7" name="personal_message"  id="share-text" style="margin-bottom:8px;" placeholder="Download Ad-Aware and help me get PRO version" ></textarea></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn_submit_step3" id="btn_friends" value="share_friends" /><br/>
                </td>
            </tr></table>
        </form>
```

controller action -----

```
public function inviteByEmailAction()
{
    $emails = $this->getRequest()->getParam('emails');
    $personal_message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('personal_message');

    $emails = explode(",", $emails);

    foreach ($emails as $email)
    {
        $email = trim($email);
        $validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
        if ($validator->isValid($email)) 
        {
            if ($this->_helper->model('EmailInvites')->noRowByFields(array('email' => $email, 'referred_by_user_id' => $this->_helper->user()->id)))
            {
                $email_invite = $this->_helper->model('EmailInvites')->createRow();  
                $email_invite->email = $email;
                $email_invite->personal_message = $personal_message;
                $email_invite->referred_by_user_id = $this->_helper->user()->id;
                $email_invite->save();

                $this->_helper->user()->sendInviteEmail($email, $personal_message);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');

}
```

And model has a function to send email.

Comment: I think I find the way out, just do a zend_validate_db_norecordexists in the controller to check the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter your emails prior to trying to send them. Look into [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

Here is psedo function to get the job done:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param array $userEnteredEmails array with all user entered emails
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getEmailsThatAreNotInDb(array $userEnteredEmails)
{
    $db = null; //  your database object
    /* @var $db Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract */

    // get all emails from DB that are in user provided list
    $query = $db->select()
            ->from('emails_table', array('email_address'))
            ->where('email_address IN (?)', $userEnteredEmails);

    $emailsInDb = $db->fetchCol($query);

    // get emails from user provided list that are not in database loaded list
    $emailNonInDb = array_diff($userEnteredEmails, $emailsInDb);

    return $emailNonInDb;
}
```